# How can I improve readability of this Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, builder-pattern

I want to improve this code in ***Kotlin***, it seems too redundant

It should be possible with .forEach and Lambda's, but I don't know how
Can anyone help please?

```
val Point1 : List<Double> = topleft
                .split(",")
                .map {
                    it
                            .trim()
                            .toDouble()
                }
        val Point2 : List<Double> = topright
                .split(",")
                .map {
                    it
                            .trim()
                            .toDouble()
                }
        val Point3 : List<Double> = bottomright
                .split(",")
                .map {
                    it
                            .trim()
                            .toDouble()
                }
        val Point4 : List<Double> = bottomleft
                .split(",")
                .map {
                    it
                            .trim()
                            .toDouble()
                }
```

In the end I want to ***have ONE List*** with all this values.
topleft, topright ... are Strings like *42.1234,54.23423*
(Geographical Coordinates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a function that you can repeat for each of your lists. Like this:

```
fun String.splitToDoubles() = split(",").map { it.trim().toDouble() }

val point1 = topleft.splitToDoubles()
val point2 = topright.splitToDoubles()
val point3 = bottomright.splitToDoubles()
val point4 = bottomleft.splitToDoubles()
```

Note that the convention in Kotlin is to have `val`s and `var`s starting with a lower case letter  (`point1`, instead of `Point1`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's very good solution with extension function ***splitToDoubles()***
About the convention I know it surely, that was by mistake.